# Selenium is taking too much time to execute a command after handing browser authentication pop up

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing a very strange issue with Selenium WebDriver. After login into the website, our application shows a basic authentication pop up which I have handled through AutoIT. Problem is after the page load, Selenium takes around 80-100 secs to execute the next command. Next Command could be anything, I am simply trying to get the title of the browser after the page load. After executing the next command in 80-100 secs, Selenium execute the rest of the command in normal speed.

Any idea what could be the issue ? I have added my code below.

```
            driver.findElement(By.id("username").sendKeys("username");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password").sendKeys("passowrd");
            driver.findElement(By.id("submit").click();


            File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.17-x64.dll"); 
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH,
                    file.getAbsolutePath());
            AutoItX autoIt = new AutoItX();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            String title = "Authentication Required";


            autoIt.winActivate(title, "");
            autoIt.winWaitActive(title);
            if (autoIt.winExists(title)) {
                autoIt.send("username{TAB}", false);
                autoIt.send("password{Enter}", false);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //
        }*/

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());       


        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sdfsdf")).getText());
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("key")).getAttribute("placeholder"));
```

In the above code, Selenium takes around 60-80 secs to execute the get Title command but after that it works pretty normal. Even if I change the order of the command in the code, result remain the same.

Comment: Are you using the latest selenium chrome driver version? It could be outdated. What happens after those 60-80 seconds, page is refreshed maybe? It could also be that, when you call `driver.getTitle()` the page is not yet loaded. You should add some `wait` condition or something.

Comment: I am using Firefox browser and no, it waits for 60-80 secs after the page is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

@Naseem: How you are saying page is already loaded.? From the code you provided, there is no condition that says to wait until page loads

Anyways, if you are not waiting until document.readystate to complete, I suggest please use the below code and give a try

```
void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

Also, Please avoid using Thread.sleep()

If the above code doesn't help then AutoIT code must be the culprit, btw, while using autoIT, what is the "Local Const $timeout" you are using.?

From the below blog, one of such AutoIT code provided.

http://seleniummonk.blogspot.in/p/handle-upload-dialog.html

Try the code from it. Put your observations here, will see if it doesn't fit your needs

Comment: With the above function, script waits for wait.until(pageLoadCondition); line for 80-100 secs. I removed Auto IT code as well but it is working same.

I tried to change the Page time out as well by using the below command but it didn't threw any exception after 10 secs.

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: try the following,with implict wait.
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Btw., Are you using chrome.? As far as I remember, pageLoadTimeout() is not implemented for chrome, (not sure in recent builds)

Comment: I tried with Implicit wait as well but it is behaving same with that. I was using FF for that but when I tried the same in IE, it is working fine. Seems like there is an application issue with FF.... I am waiting for development team to take a look at FF issue. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Btw, Don't forget to update the post if you hear anything from dev team..